# I need to specify rows that must be on the same page using longtable. How can I?

Tags: latex, longtable

I have long table of pictures and descriptions (I use `longtable` environment to get it in several columns on page). I want this to be splitted past picture, not between middle title and picture. My table looks like this:

```
\multicolumn{3}{2}{description} \\
\includegraphics[]{} &
\includegraphics[]{} &
\includegraphics[]{} \\
\multicolumn{3}{2}{description} \\
\includegraphics[]{} &
\includegraphics[]{} &
\includegraphics[]{} \\
...
```

I want LaTeX to split this between pages before `\multicolumn`, not between `\multicolumn` and `\includegraphics`.
Is there possibility to do this or I should try another way?

I tried to use `\multirow{3}{*}{ }` to stick rows together but it isn't work.

Comment: It would definitely be worth asking this on the [TeX site](http://tex.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Did you try `\nopagebreak` already?

Maybe you could also describe a bit more how you want your output too look like?

Answer (score 4):

Standard `longtable` documentation says that `\\*` is "The same as `\\` but disallows a page break after the row."

Comment: Today I found \\\* in LaTeX documentation (lshort). It works and I think it's the best answer.